# french charcters are not showing in proper format

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, character-encoding

I am storing some french content in database but it converted to `?`.

String : `médiévaux, principalement pour l’anglais et le français`, is converted to `médiévaux, principalement pour l??anglais et le français`,

I have applied utf-8 encoding to jsp page, and to the servlets as well.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

and in servlets

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

I have also tried with decoding the string

```
return (string != null) ? new String(string.getBytes(), UTF8_CHARSET) : null;
```

and then encode it.

```
return (string != null) ? new String(string.getBytes(UTF8_CHARSET)) : null;
```

code of getting from JSP and setting it in a servlet

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
String content = request.getParameter("inputFr");
        if(content == null){
            throw new Exception("exception");
        }

        content = new String(string.getBytes(), UTF8_CHARSET);
```

but still the question marks appearing in the above content string. Any Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't support those characters. You need to use UTF-16.

Comment: @Antonijn: you're wrong. UTF-8 supports french character sets.

Comment: As far as I understand the french characters are not the problem, it's just the apostrophe `'`, correct?

Comment: @home You're right. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: How do you insert the values into the database? Keep in mind that the apostrophe is a reserved character in SQL...

Comment: @home yes you are right the problem lies over at this character '

Comment: I set this french text in a string and simple save it. but when i inspect that string it contains black diamond with ? in it.

Comment: @Java_NewBie: *How* do you write the values into the database (show the code)? I somehow bet you just use a `Statament` instead of a `PreparedStatement`...

Comment: @home well actually I am using EJB's for it to save an entity. That entity has variable which is use to store this french text.

Comment: @home but before saving it when I inspect that variable which holds the french text it contains the ? against the apostrophe '. So i think there is not an issue while saving it in the DB, the issue is before saving it.

Comment: So you must check where it changes from apostrophe to `?`. Check the full path like HTML> HTTP > Servlet > EJB > Entity...

Comment: Actually when my jsp sends a variable to the servlet it contains the french text. I am getting this as "String content = request.getParameter("inputFr");" in the servlet, so in the servlet part it is all happening, and before all this process i am doing the proper encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you send parameter in the URL that is not encoded. To encode it use 
`URLEncoder.encode(content, "UTF-8");`. You can decode it in the JSP as

```
  <%
    out.println(java.net.URLDecoder.decode(((String[])request.getParameterMap().get("inputFr"))[0], "UTF-8"));
  %>
```

Comment: ohhhh ok let me try that, sorry for miss understood.

Comment: This answer is nonsense. Request parameters from `getParameterXxx()` methods are already URL decoded. See also javadoc. Only `getQueryString()` is not URL decoded.

Comment: @BalusC any answer for my question?